ZFS corruption, how to restore file
# zpool status -v                                                                                                                                          
  pool: data-2024-06-04                                                              
 state: ONLINE                                                                       
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data               
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.                                   
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the             
        entire pool from backup.                                                                                                                                           
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A                       
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 01:00:45 with 1 errors on Fri Jul  5 03:23:14 2024      
config:                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                           
        NAME                                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM                                                                                                    
        data-2024-06-04                      ONLINE       0     0     0              
          raidz1-0                           ONLINE       0     0     0                                                                                                    
            ata-ST4000NE001-2MA101_WS253ZJH  ONLINE       0     0     4              
            ata-ST4000NE001-2MA101_WS254FSH  ONLINE       0     0     4              
                                                                                     
errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:                  
                                                                                     
        data-2024-06-04@2024-06-10-initial:/server-data6/server-WD-WCAU4C302236-part1/pics/[...]/dsc05151.jpg
        /data-2024-06-04/pics/[...]/dsc05151.jpg  

I have a copy of the specific file in question elsewhere. Can I just copy it back? Specifically, on

Restore the file in question if possible

How to restore it?
I copied it over the live file system (/data-2024-06-04/pics/...) and now that entry disappeared, but the first one (data-2024-06-04@2024-06-10-initial:...) is still there.
I'm now running another zpool scrub data-2024-06-04 in the hope that it somehow detects the new file, notice that it matches the checksum and that also fixes the other corruption, but I somehow doubt this.
I also wonder a bit, how could this corruption have happened in the first place? Shouldn't a raidz protect me from this? I don't see any disk errors in dmesg, and the disks are  new (Seagate IronWolf Pro 4TB).
